# gitignoring Android Studio app

Tags: android, android-studio, gitignore

In the file structure, you have

- Project Name

  - .idea
  - app

    - build
    - libs
    - src
    - app.iml
    - build.gradle
  - build
  - gradle
  - ...

I have .gitignored the **build** in the Project Name directory, but is it safe and should I also .gitignore **build** in the app directory?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe. Files in build folder can be regenerated when you re-import the project next time.